# How can I get second or third commit id?

Tags: git

I want to get specific git id in history.
I know how to do it only for the latest one:

```
$ git log -n 1 --format=%H
```

But how can I get the `n`th most recent commit?

Comment: `git log -n 2 --format=%H|tail -n 1`

Comment: Thank you Leion!! Great!

Comment: `git rev-parse HEAD~3`  but with merge you will have issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get *`i`*'th most recent commit using `tail`:

**`git log -n`** *`i`* **`--format=%H|tail -n 1`**

Example (get 10th commit)

**`git log -n 10 --format=%H|tail -n 1`**

---

A git-only way:

**`git log --skip`** *`(i-1)`* **`-n 1 --format=%H`**

Example (get 10th commit)

**`git log --skip 9 -n 1 --format=%H`**

Comment: you're awesome, thanks for this great command, now I can use it to get commit on the gitlab ci cd

Answer (score 3):

Replace 1 by  `n-1`

```
git rev-parse HEAD~1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following command:

```
git rev-list -n 3 HEAD | tail -1
```